# Filling two arrays from text document in java

Tags: java, arrays, search, netbeans, search-engine

I want to take word from text document and then search for it in a string array. If the word exist then i will increment its value in another integer array if not I will add it to the string array and increment its value in the integer array.

At the end of the code I must have two arrays. A string one that contains word of that documents and the integer array that contains each word how much repeated in the used document.
But my code gives me an null pointer exception. Why?

```
   try{
      FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\IRP\\finalstemmer\\Algorithm.stp");
     FileReader reader2 = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\IRP\\finalstemmer\\Algorithm.stp");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(reader2);
        String word ,word2 , newWord;
    int n =0;
    while ((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    n++;}
    System.out.println(n);
     String [] anArray = new String[n];
      int [] count = new int[n];

       while ((word2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {

           for (int k = 0; k < word2.split(" ").length; k++) {
       newWord = word2.split(" ")[k];
      int i = 0;


      while(!anArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(newWord)){
           if(anArray[i].equals(null))
       break;
       i++;
     }
      if(anArray[i].equals(null)){
         anArray[i]=newWord;
         count[i]++;  
      }else 
      if(anArray[i].equals(newWord)){
         count[i]++;
      }
       }
       }

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArray));
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
    }catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    } // TODO code applicat
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Can you post your whole code and the error logs?

Comment: this is my whole code

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE?

Comment: Sorry, but don't know what is NPE? I am a beginner in java..

Comment: Null Pointer exception

Comment: I used SOP to test my code. when it arrives to the while loop it stop printing any thing I do not know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a HashSet very efficiently.
if you can successfully add the word then the word does not exist in the HashSet. HashSet contains the unique element. and according to that just increase your counter array which should hold the word wise counter

here is a sample code to explain the basic stratigy

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sal[]={"val","sa","de","dal","val","sa","de"}; // just an example array of word
        HashSet<String> ss = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(sal)); // any Hash set containing String Element
        System.out.println("HashSet-");
        System.out.println(ss);

        if(ss.add("vald")){ // word does not exists
            System.out.println("Not exist");
            // Do your code here 
        }else{
            //word exist just increase the array couter
        }


    }
```

o/p:

```
HashSet-
[de, val, sa, dal]
Not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` to check if an object is null or not.

So `if(yourObject == null)` is the right way.

Second thing is Strings should be split like this:

```
word2.split("\\s+").length
```